# How to bind an entire element of an Observable Collection to a ContentView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

In my View code I create an object of the type of my Model. I add that object to an ObservableCollection and bind to that collection in my XAML code for a StackLayout. I have place a custom control, a ContentView, inside the StackLayout. I want to be able to set a property on the control using the entire object in the ObservableCollection. The control will then set its own content from the parts of the object set. If this is a little confusing, let me demonstrate what I want to do.

**UPDATE**
I have modified my code, both XAML and C#, to try several ways to access the current element in the source collection based on the info provided by Jason(below in the comments) and using info I found in the [Binding Declarations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview).

Here is the revised XAML:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding IdCardCollection}"
                             Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" >
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <!-- Content -->
                <Frame HeightRequest="360" Margin="17, 0, 16, 0" 
                                       BorderColor="{StaticResource NGIC_GrayishWhite}" 
                                       HasShadow="True">
                    <Grid Margin="-10, -13, -10, 5">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="80*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="260*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="73*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <cardViews:ThreeLineCardView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                                                     Margin="0, 0, 10, 0"
                                                                     ConfigName="IdCard"
                                                                     HeightRequest="59"
                                                                     WidthRequest="335"
                                                                     CardInfo="{Binding Path=/}"
                                                                     CardTitle="{Binding StateTerritoryCardTitle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

On the CardInfo property **I have also tried the following without any success
{Binding .} and {Binding}**

The code for the control:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CardInfoProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CardInfo), typeof(IdCard), typeof(ThreeLineCardView), null);

private IdCard _idCard;

public IdCard CardInfo 
{
    get => (IdCard)GetValue(CardInfoProperty);
    set
    {
       SetValue(CardInfoProperty, value);
        _idCard = (IdCard) value;
    }
}
```

And the collection that the page is bound to is defined as in the ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<IdCard> IdCardCollection { get; private set; }
```

I know that the element exists because the second property I set in the control, CardTitle, does work.

**UPDATE 2**
Tried using an object as the property type and that did not work either (I set a breakpoint on the SetValue method call in the property setter). See below:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CardInfoObjectProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CardInfoObject), typeof(object), typeof(ThreeLineCardView), null);
```

```
        public object CardInfoObject
        {
            get => GetValue(CardInfoObjectProperty);
            set
            {
                SetValue(CardInfoObjectProperty, value);
                _idCard = (IdCard)value;
                SetIdCardValues(_idCard);
            }
        }
```

```
<cardViews:ThreeLineCardView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                                                     Margin="0, 0, 10, 0"
                                                                     ConfigName="IdCard"
                                                                     HeightRequest="59"
                                                                     WidthRequest="335"
                                                                     CardInfoObject="{Binding .}"
                                                                     CardTitle="{Binding StateTerritoryCardTitle}"/>
```

Comment: If you have solved this issue, please accept answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

to bind the entire object, using `"{Binding .}"`

Comment: Any idea where this is documented? I would love to delve further into the Binding capabilities.

Comment: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview) Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current source. For example, Text="{Binding}" is equivalent to Text="{Binding Path=.}"

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to what is happening during the binding, aven after reading everything I can find on the subject. In my control, how would I define the property that will be set when I do the "{Binding .}"? If I follow what you're saying, then the ItemSource is an ObservableCollection. Using this Binding will send the entire collection to the property?

Comment: no, when you use a template, the binding context will be the current element of the collection, not the entire collection.

Comment: Even though I accepted this as the answer, that was based on the info you gave and the documentation you pointed me to. However, I still can't get the object that is the current element in the collection. I'm updating the code in the question to show the different ways I've tried to access the entire current element in the source collection.

Comment: this absolutely works - I have used it hundreds of times.  However, it may be passed to your custom control as an object, and you may have to cast it.

Comment: Tried that (see UPDATE 2) and still can't get it to work. I guess I'll have to use separate properties for everything :(

Comment: @JNickVA1 If it not works, could you share a demo about this issue in github.